# Can I open the page tree in TYPO3 with one click?

Tags: typo3

A customer wanted to know, if we could implement a function in the TYPO3 backend, were all pages and subpages are flipped open in the pagetree in one click so you don't have to open each page individually by clicking on the opening icon.

So my question is, if there is any possibility to have the page tree fully opened in the backend without having to open each subpage manually?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!
Kind regards,
Anniasks

Comment: Seems like a valid feature request. Please file it on https://forge.typo3.org

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It's a question about the user interface of a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality existed in TYPO3 before 8.x. Later it was silently removed when internal components for the page tree were refactored. Some  javascript functions for this functionality remain in TYPO3 v8 and even v9 but user interface for it was removed.

I know this because the customer asked to bring it back in a project.

[image]

My solution was local to the project and would not be easy to ingerate back to stock TYPO3.